# Restricting direct access to file deny ajax request as well

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I want to deny direct access to all php files. So I use the below command in my .htaccess file. It works fine that direct access is disabled, but I can include any php file in my index.php. But the issue occurs when all my ajax requests from index.php are blocked as well. How can I unblock my ajax requests?

**This is forbidden (as expected):**

> http://www.example.com/other.php

**This is goes thru (as expected):**

> http://www.example.com/index.php

**This goes thru (as expected) in index.php:**

```
include(other.php)
```

**But this returns Forbidden as well in index.php:**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "other.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ field: field})
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

**.htaccess**

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
</FilesMatch>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: You can't. You can put them each in a different directory and name them index.php or you could create an ajax directory with those files and put an exception in for everything inside ajax.

Comment: Can please elaborate a bit? Did you mean I shouldn't restrict direct access by htaccess to php files which I call through Ajax? In that case is there any way that I deny direct access to those php files?

Comment: Any file you call through ajax has to be accessible. If you block it for a direct call, it can't be called through ajax because ajax is a direct call happening from the client's browser.

Comment: ohk ... thanks for clarifying this ..

Comment: What you can do is make the script accessible and within the logic of the script determine if the requesting user has the proper authentication/authorization. If not, send back a 401.

Comment: What if I use a common unrestricted file ajaxcall.php to call through ajax. Then inside ajaxcall.php, I include restricted php files (e.g. other.php). Will this work?

Comment: Yes, that will work. But what's the difference, if you can access them through a shell file vs directly?

Comment: You are right. that was a stupid thought ... my target is nobody can access other.php directly, and my method is not ging to do any good for that.

Comment: What is `other.php` doing that you're trying to protect? Instead of trying to block direct access, it should be checking something alone the lines of `if(!$authenticated){  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'); exit; }` Making a request is the same regardless if it's typed in through the browser or you have javascript that makes an ajax call. The user has 100% identical access to the data in both instances. In other words, even if you could make it only available through ajax, you have the exact same security issue that you would if they could type it in.

Comment: hmm right. other.php actually returns some sensitive data of userX if user is logged in which is shown in a div in index.php. But I don't want the user to get the data directly by browsing example.com/other.php. It's more about intended method of delivery that security concern.

Comment: There is either security or no security. What you are proposing is no security.

Comment: well .. when I say not security, I meant even if user able to get the data directly, it won't result any disaster as he has to be logged in for direct access (other.php is secured thru some session variable check).

Comment: If it's secured through a session check, there's no reason to block access. The user will only have access if the session is valid.

Comment: yaa .. agreed .. it just bothers me that he can get the data by direct access, rather than through my index page :) .. I guess that's childish thought ...